# Stripe Session with Shipping fee

Tags: stripe-payments

How can I add shipping fee to stripe session create.

Here is what the have so far:
`

```
$line_items = [
                        'price_data' => [
                          'product_data' => [
                              'name' => $product->title
                          ],
                          'unit_amount' => $product->price * 100,
                          'currency' => 'cad',
                        ],
                        'quantity' => $product->qty
                    ];

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'success_url' => $domain . '/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            'cancel_url' => $domain . '/cart',
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'line_items' => [$line_items]
        ]);
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have Stripe calculate shipping. In order to include a shipping amount, you can either increase the unit_amount on your current line item, or add another line item for the shipping total.

I would recommend creating the full product catalog inside of Stripe and consider using a standard Product for Shipping, then use a derived amount for the unit amount on that shipping price data with the standard Shipping product.

Comment: Not all websites can have their products listed on Stripe. My website is a marketplace where sellers list their own products and each have their own shipping pricing.

Comment: In that case, then I would recommend creating ad-hoc prices and products one for the good being purchased and one for the taxes for that good.

Comment: that's waaaay complicated. It shouldn't be like that. Checkout v2 was easier that way. You have an amount to charge period. It's not being controlled from Stripe's end. That's why I am using Checkout.js for ease of use.

Comment: Can you share what you were doing with legacy Checkout and we can see more details about what you're trying to achieve? It actually seems easier to do this with line items and prices than it would've been with the old way so I'm curious to see what the real goal is here.